# C++ and returning a reference

Tags: c++, reference

Can any one explain to me the difference between these two functions:

```
int& test(int a)
{
    return a;
}
```

and

```
int test(int a)
{
    return a;
}
```

and tell me what the purpose when we use '&' operator after return type of a function?
When should we use it because I've rarely seen it before.

Comment: You generally don't want to use it as the return type for the exact reason displayed here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2273821/78845

Comment: It is not an "operator". It is just `&` character that happens to be the same character used in some operators.

Comment: ok, thanks every one, the best thing I got from that link is :
"if you need to return a value, return a value and don't worry about any "expense".
anyway, thanks for you helps @@

Comment: The first method is intended to return a reference of a given variable. It`s normally used when passing parameters. Whereby, you pass a reference as an input. The second method, just return the value of the variable A and not a reference. There is a difference between passing a variable by a value and passing a variable by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can any one explain to me the difference between these two functions?

The first example may yield undefined behavior because the returned reference "points" to a variable that, at the end of the function, gets destroyed. This is very similar (almost identical) to the definition of [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

The second case is the normal, "correct" way of returning the variable in the example specified above.

---

> and tell me what the purpose when we use '&' operator after return type of a function?

The purpose of a `&` after a type in the return statement is to return a reference to that type.

---

> When should we use it because I've rarely seen it before.

Generally, passing a reference or returning a reference is useful to avoid making a copy of the parameter being passed/returned, which may be costly.

Since C++11 there's a better way of handling returning big objects: [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics).

In other cases it is used to provide access to internal members of a class. This is the example of `std::string::operator[]` for example:

```
char& operator[] (size_t pos);
const char& operator[] (size_t pos) const;
```

It may also be used to allow function call chains. This is the case of:

```
std::cout << 'H' << 'e' << 'l' << 'l' << 'o';
```

for example. In the code above, the `std::ostream::operator<<` returns a reference to itself.

Comment: I dont know the exactly way to explain what it should be, cause I'm not well at English,
but I wonder what the "purpose" when we use & after return type.

may be the example below doesn't show the exactly way, that just what I think, sorry about that.

I just want to know the 'purpose' when we use it.

thanks for you comment :D

Comment: @dinhha471, Take a look at the new edit.

Comment: In my opinion, although returning a reference to an int may be legal 'C', as someone pointed out above, the function is returning a reference to a variable on the functions stack. So, when you try to access it, you may get an access violation or SEGV.

Comment: @Jeffrey :
It's just what I wonder when I see some function in C/C++ library.
But in real, I never use it so far.
Your explaination so good, I couldn't vote for you (cause I'm not enough reputation), Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4305673/78845

Answer (score 0):

'&' operator after return type means that the function returns a reference. It makes sense it getter methods like

```
class A{
public:
     int &val(){return _val;}
private:
     int _val;
};
```

The advantage is that you can both read and modify the state of the object. For example:

```
A a;
a.val() = 10;
```

But it in your case it is probably better to pass a reference to a function rather then return it:

```
void test(int &a)
{
    //do something with a
}
```

It is not good to return a reference to a function local object, for example:

```
int& test()
{
    int x;    
    return x;
}
```

because `x` doesn't exists outside test() function.

Comment: thanks for mention getter and setter, it easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

The first one is dangerous, because of the variable scope. If you want to do it this way, you should make the variable static.